# How to use DPLYR functions to get information from external database applying filters correctly?

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, filter

I have this information:

"table_information"

| num | date_inf |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022/01/01 |
| 2 | 2022/02/01 |
| 3 | 2022/03/01 |
| 4 | 2022/04/01 |
| 5 | 2022/05/01 |

Using this connection and code i can filter without problem:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), Driver = "{MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver}",
             Server = "{host}", database = "db", UID = "userid",
             PWD = "pwd",
             Port = 1234)
```

I can filter without problem with this:

```
temp<-tbl(con,sql("select * from table_information where num=3")) #or the next sentence
temp<-tbl(con,sql("select * from table_information where date_inf>'2022-03-01'"))
```

Then i can convert it and work with it:

```
temp<-temp%>%as_tibble()
```

But when i try to do with filter using dplyr i get error:

```
temp<-tbl(con,"table_information")
temp%>%filter(num==3) #or the next sentence
temp%>%filter(date_inf >'2022-03-01')
```

I get this error for both columns, (date_inf and num):

```
Error in storage.mode(x) <- "double" : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

not even adding

```
%>% collect() or as_tibble()
```

num is int - str(table_information$num) and date_inf is date - str(table_information$date_inf)

I see the result of tbl like a list, but i don't know if is necessary to apply unlist() or what i'm doing wrong? i thought filters could apply directly. I want to use dplyr only, not SQL code.

Edit:
however the objects seem to have loaded fine, it seems a problem with filter

```
 tbl(con,"table_information")

  |num   |date_inf  |
  |------|----------|
  |<int> |<date>    |    
  |   1  |2022-01-01|
  |  2   |2022-02-01|
  |  3   |2022-03-01|
  | 4    |2022-04-01|
  | 5    |2022-05-01|
```

Comment: Maybe your format is `Date` class i.e. `2022/01/01`, so it can be `filter(as.Date(date_int, format = "%Y/%m/%d") > as.Date("2022-03-01"))`

Comment: Can you show the `str(table_information)`

Comment: Could be linked to https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3162

Comment: Here str tibble [5 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame) $ num : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5 $ date_inf : Date[1:5], format: "2022-01-01" "2022-02-01" "2022-03-01" "2022-04-01" ...

we focus in date, ok could be different format, but what about "num"? is an integer, i tried like character and it is the same, i don't see any logical explanation.

Comment: I just fixed guys, thanks for your help anyway, was a conflict with function filter of the package "stats", i just deleted this package and works the same code.

Comment: Ummm ... "deleted this package"? `stats` is ingrained into R, it is installed by default with R (_always_), it should never be removed from the R installation. It has many functions that may not immediately seem like stat-functions (e.g., `setNames`). The canonical way would be to prepend `dplyr::` to your calls to `filter` (for specificity), or more likely just make sure you `library(dplyr)` _after_ anything that directly or implicitly imports the `stats` package.

Comment: I decided to use this

library(conflicted)
    conflict_prefer("filter", "dplyr", "stats")